# Le/les creo a mis amigos

Tags: gramática, pronombres

Una de mis amigas suele decir:

```
Yo le creo a mis amigos.
```

Pero para mi tendría más sentido si "amigos" y el pronombre personal fueran en plural:

```
Yo les creo a mis amigos.
```

Esto suena mal a mi amiga, pero puedo encontrar ambas formas en ejemplos para ilustrar puntos gramaticales de español. ¿Por qué puede ser? ¿Sólo es una diferencia regional?

Otro ejemplo:

```
Ella le escribe a sus padres una carta.
```

y

```
Ella les escribe a sus padres una carta.
```

Comment: Ninguna de las opciones me suena demasiado bien. ¿Qué quiere decir con esta frase? Lo más parecido me parece a mí `Creo a mis amigos`, pero no sé si es el mismo significado que las frases que mencionas.

Comment: Gracias. Modifiqué las frases un poquito. ¿Ahora está más claro?

Comment: ¿De dónde es tu amiga?  En los acentos aspirantes, la *s* tiende a aspirarse o perderse incluso más frente a consonantes plosivos.

Comment: Es de Colombia. A veces la _s_ se pierde, sí. Pero también escribe así (y es buena escritora).

Answer (score 11):

No hay ninguna ambigüedad en el asunto: siempre **debe existir concordancia** de número (y de género en otros casos) entre el pronombre y el referente. Por lo tanto sólo estos casos son correctos:

> Ella **le** dice a **él**.
>
> Ella **les** dice a **ellos**.

Cualquier otro caso es incorrecto, aunque su uso sea habitual.

Lee el item **6.a** de lo referente a **pronombres personales átonos** en el [Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=elLl31yYnD65MTS9uF#6).

Comment: Gracias, muy interesante. Aún más porque "les" no parece gramatical a algunas personas. Sospecho que es menos ignorancia de la regla correcta y más una costumbre profunda.

Comment: +1 Excelente respuesta. Siempre tuve la idea errónea, citando el segundo ejemplo, de que si se especificaba 'a ellos' entonces era válido decir 'Ella le dice'.

Comment: Es habitual porque el plural de cierta palabra se le puede referir a algo abstrato que se considera como algo único, junto, inseparable...