# "Dale un beso a los niños" - what does "le" stand for?

Tags: objetos-indirectos, imperativo

In this text two people (married couple) are talking to another on the phone. One says to the other:

> Dale un beso a los niños.

"Dale" seems to be imperative + dative. But who does "le" refer to? If it was the kids, shouldn't it be in plural ("les")?

If this is a case of the list in

[All about datives, or: What's that funny "le" or "me" doing in there?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/all-about-datives-or-whats-that-funny-le-or-me-doing-in-there)

which one is it?

Comment: I've just found a [very similar question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13475/le-les-creo-a-mis-amigos). It's in Spanish and the answer was not marked as accepted but it's correct.

Comment: Similar: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19301/what-is-the-grammar-behind-hágale-pues

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The text is mistaken. The pronoun should be *les*.

In the text, the dative pronoun *le* is the indirect object, and anticipates the full indirect object, *a los niños*. This (showing the IO through a pronoun and then a full nominal phrase) is extremely common, and it's grammatically correct. What is not correct is, as you've guessed, that *le* is singular but the full indirect object is plural.

This mistake (failing to make the indirect object pronoun and full phrase agree in number) is [also very common](https://www.delcastellano.com/errores-concordancia-objeto-indirecto/), to the point of being present in textbooks and reference works. It's so common that I, being a native speaker, found nothing wrong with the sentence at first sight, and had to check whether it **was** really a mistake, because it sounded so natural I thought it just couldn't be.

It's possible that people tend to use *le* instead of *les* because the fact that it's often not right next to the plural phrase it refers to makes the speaker forget the agreement, and also because *le* is automatically associated with *se*, which has no plural. The former reason sounds implausible to me, since I (and many people I know) constantly utter sentences where *le* is immediately followed by an indirect object phrase, without registering the mistake:

> *Dale a los niños un beso.*

Finally, this is not an instance of a "funny dative"; it's just a plain indirect object, used with the most frequent of the ditransitive verbs, *dar*, here in the singular imperative (*da*).

Comment: Puede ser también que el hablante no pronuncia bien la ‘s’ al final de ‘dales’ y por eso para los hablantes de español no nativos, suena como si dijera ‘dale’

Comment: @Traveller Puede ser, pero incluso los que aspiramos la /s/ final tendemos a marcar la separación cuando sigue una vocal: *da-leh-a-loh-ni-ñoh...*. Si en cambio nunca hubo una /s/, la vocal que sigue hace [sinalefa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinalefa): *da-le̯a-loh-ni-ñoh*. Esto último es lo que yo oigo.

Comment: Could this sound natural because it is actually a syntactic expletive which seems to be common in Spanish commands such as in the case of ándale, márcale, ábrele, órale, hágale and so on? See: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19574/12672